# If heaven is not monotonous why would this world be monotonous if God willed to happen in that fashion?

Tags: heaven, good-and-evil

I have a question that I have been thinking about for a long time now.

Here it is. Heaven is the place where good people will end up. There are two types of evil.  Natural evil like volcanic eruption, earthquake, flood, drought etc. And there is Volitional evil which is the consequence of human actions. Like unjust wars and genocide. God gave us free will and we can choose. If God rewarded all the good people for good acts and punished the bad people for bad deeds or stop the Natural disasters from occurring then the world would be monotonous and predictable and won't follow the natural order.

But then in heaven everything is orderly, has unwavering and everlasting joy and felicity and is not monotonous for a single day.

I am not challenging God's judgement. I believe in God. I just like to know  Him better. In heaven there is no evil and life is not boring for a single day. If heaven is not monotonous in any way why would this world be monotonous if He had willed to remove all the evil from the face of the earth? After all God is ominous and almighty. He can make everything possible on earth and in the universe.

Comment: You have left Jesus Christ out of your thoughts and considerations about 'good' and 'free will' and 'reward' and 'punishment'. And regarding 'heaven'. It seems you are managing all of this on your own.

Comment: I understand the first part. But could you kindly clarify the last part about Heaven? You agree that it's right to think heaven is not a boring place but a vibrant place of God.

Comment: Those who believe in Jesus Christ enter the kingdom of heaven, now. Here and now.Heaven is where God is, the Father and the Son.

Comment: Were there any natural disasters in the Garden of Eden ? If not, was Paradise a monotonous place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **God is Love**

> Whoever does not love does not know God, because God is love. (1 John 4:8)

2. **Definition of Ultimate Love**

> Greater love has no one than this: to lay down one’s life for one’s
>   friends. (John 15:13)

3. **Magnification of Ultimate Love**

> 6 You see, at just the right time, when we were still powerless,
>   Christ died for the ungodly. 7 Very rarely will anyone die for a
>   righteous person, though for a good person someone might possibly dare
>   to die. 8 But God demonstrates his own love for us in this: While we
>   were still sinners, Christ died for us. (Romans 5:6-8)

4. **Christ's Love is Ultimate Love**

> This is how we know what love is: Jesus Christ laid down his life for
>   us. And we ought to lay down our lives for our brothers and sisters.
>   (1 John 3:16)

5. **It was God's Will that Christ Prove God's Ultimate Love**

> 41 He withdrew about a stone’s throw beyond them, knelt down and
>   prayed, 42 “Father, if you are willing, take this cup from me; yet not
>   my will, but yours be done.” (Luke 22:41-42)

God is humble. He does not boast about who He is and what He can do, He proves who He is and what He can do. He does this by making a promise and then fulfilling it. Thus the eternal bliss we may enjoy in Heaven is built upon the sure foundation of God's actual, demonstrated love for us. Christ had to die for those God loved, but to be an even greater demonstration of love, the ones he died for had to be sinners. And if there are to be sinners in this world, then there must be suffering and death, God's justice and stern discipline whereby he teaches us wisdom and perfects us through trials.

Our sin and suffering make us suitable objects of Christ's love to display the Glory of God and lay the foundation for a perfect heaven. The cornerstone of the new Jerusalem is Christ and its foundation is the Apostles and Prophets.

Without the evil and suffering of this world, God would lack the proper foundation on which to build the next. Why? Everyone in Heaven will know personally this one truth: *If God loved me enough to die for me while I was a sinner, He will never in the eternity spread out before me abandon me or stop loving me now that I am a saint.*